# Which is the best way to iterate the list of elements from bottom to up?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

```
for (int i = listofdisplayedDates.size(); i >= 1; i--)
{
    WebElement Test = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='session']//div[@class='hrlis'][+i+]")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.Hope this will help.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
List<WebElement> listofdisplayedDates =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@id='session']//div[@class='hrlis']")));
for (int i =listofdisplayedDates.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        WebElement Test =listofdisplayedDates.get(i);
    }
```

Comment: If it resolved your problem please accept the answer by clicking hollow under down vote button.so it will turn as green.Thanks.